# How can I align 3 Images (Logos) in a row over the hole width and keep them aligned that way on smaller displays

Tags: html, css, image, alignment

I'll try to align 3 Logos with the same height but with different widths on a row over the hole screen-width: The first image should be aligned at the left end of the screen, the third one should be aligned at the right end of the screen and the second one should float in between the other two images with the same space between them. The space should get smaller when the display gets smaller until it hit a defined minimum space. From there on if the display gets further smaller the hole row should scale down. I hope the image helps in clarify what I have in mind.

[how it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmL0n.png)

It's for a MailChimp Newsletter.

That is how far I got:

```css
.my-logo-container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.my-logos{
flex: 1;
border: 1px solid red;
height: auto;
max-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-logo-container">
  <div class="my-logos">
    <a href="https://via.placeholder.com/100x80.png">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x80.png">
    </a>
  </div>
   <div class="my-logos">
    <a href="https://via.placeholder.com/195x80.png">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/195x80.png">
    </a>
  </div>
   <div class="my-logos">
    <a href="https://via.placeholder.com/175x80.png">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/175x80.png">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any Help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this solution: Instead of defining a minimum space in css I added more space into the images themselves. Now they can touch eachother and it still looks good. With display: flex; and justify-content: space-between; I arranged them in a row. With   max-width: 100%; and height: auto; the Images auto-resizes on smaller screens. It works for me now.

```css
.logo-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.logo {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo-container">
<img class="logo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x80.png">
<img class="logo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/195x80.png">
<img class="logo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/175x80.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an alternative for you. Did you mean this?

```css
.my-logo-container{
  width: 100%;
  margin:0;
}

ul.my-logos{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

ul.my-logos li{
    width: 32.33333%;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin:0;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    border:1px solid red;
}
ul.my-logos li a img{
    max-width: 130px;
    height:80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-logo-container">
  <ul class="my-logos">
    <li>
      <a href="https://via.placeholder.com/100x80.png">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x80.png">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://via.placeholder.com/195x80.png">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/195x80.png">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://via.placeholder.com/175x80.png">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/175x80.png">
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But that doesn’t work for me yet. Maybe I want too much with my modest ability…

I have edited my description above and added an image to clarify what I have in mind.

Comment: Hmm... I still don't understand what do you expect.
Or maybe you can add an exception for li:first-child = text-align : left; and li:last-child = text-align : right;